# Can you reupload an app bundle with same version code if you pause an open test track?

Tags: android, google-play

We've commenced roll out of our app via our open testing track. However, we've spotted an issue and we'd like to pause the current testing track. If we pause it, can we reupload a fixed AAB with the same version code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot reupload a fixed AAB with the same version code if you pause the current testing track. The version code must be unique for each release of your app, so you'll need to increment the version code before uploading the fixed AAB.

Comment: Hey akubi. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hey @Hanif Shaikh, indeed, the version code needs to be increased. Thanks.